# resetForm() triggering submitHandler and not resetting form values/highlightstates

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have got a problem using JQuery plugin Validation.
First of all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/VJKBc/

I have got a form that is being validated by mentioned plugin. The submitbutton ("Speichern") works as expected.

But the resetbutton ("Zurücksetzen") also triggers form validation and does not reset values and highlight.

Can someone please point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i tried some things and nothing worked out very well.

So i made a little workaround and moved the `buttons` out of the `form`, asigned a click function to both of them and did everthing within the click functions.

Only thing to worry about is, that my buttons are no longer belonging to the `form`. But since my `form` is in a `fieldset` it all matches together.

Heres the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJKBc/4/)